# How to prevent Twilio room disconnect leaving redundant video and audio elements on page

Tags: angular, twilio

I am new to Twilio and I'm developing a prototype to research the video functionality.

I am using two machines to test.  I creating a room on one machine, then join the room from a second machine.  When the second machine joins then I display the second machine video track within a DIV in the UI.

I use a div in the UI to host the video track, as follows:

```
<div id="remote-media-div"></div>
```

Here is my code for attaching the remote track to the div (targetting the remote-media-div):

```
this.room.on('participantConnected', (participant:any) => {
      
      console.log(`Participant connected: ${participant.identity}`);
      participant.on('trackSubscribed', (track:any) => {
        console.log(`Participant trackSubscribed `);
        (document.getElementById('remote-media-div') as HTMLElement).appendChild(track.attach());
      });

    });
```

The remote machine camera view is then displayed correctly within the UI on the first machine.  Fine.

I then disconnect the first machine with the following code:

```
this.room.disconnect();
```

This works ok, but it leaves the div that was 'hosting' the view with redundant `<video>` and `<audio>` HTML elements.  The UI then looks like this, where the black area is the redundant video element and the green border identifies the remote-media-div DIV :

[image]

Inspecting the HTML shows the child HTML elements that have been left hanging around:

[image]

So, how should I ensure that the HTML elements that are added by Twilio are then removed when the user disconnects from the room?

Answer (score 0):

So, after further research I spotted the participant 'trackUnsubscribed' event.  After the `this.room.disconnect();` then these events fire for the relevant remote participants and can be used to remove the HTML elements that were added to support that track.

Here is the revised code:

```
this.room.on('participantConnected', (participant:any) => {
      
      console.log(`Participant connected: ${participant.identity}`);
      participant.on('trackSubscribed', (track:any) => {
        console.log(`Participant trackSubscribed `);
        (document.getElementById('remote-media-div') as HTMLElement).appendChild(track.attach());
      });

      participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', (track:any) => {
        const attachedElements = track.detach();
        attachedElements.forEach((element:any) => element.remove());
        console.log(`Participant trackUnsubscribed`);
      });

    });
```

It works nicely and removes the relevant HTML elements.